# How share node_modules across two node projects with PNPM?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, pnpm

i have a project with two nodeJS projects inside, a backend project with inside a folder "client" for the frontend.
Now i would like to make one common node_moduels folder both.

I found that PNPM could do that, but for me the documentation is not so clear. How doest it work?
How can i run pnpm i on my root folder and then make my node_modules accessable for my "client" folder?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux or Mac, i usually symlink the module (`ln -s`) into my other projects' libs. Then i `import` or `require` the module from there. It's located directly in your codebase, not in `node_modules`, but it works just fine.

Just don't update the common module without keeping in mind all the dependant projects.

For easy versioning, you may choose to [publish your module to `npm`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish) (even as private), and update it with each push for each of the dependants.